# Trim Monday to MON using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

This select statement shows if the date is monday,tuesday etc..

```
  Select DATENAME(dw,  CAST([DateTime] as Date)) as DayName
```

What i wanted to do is to trim the word monday into mon or tuesday to tue is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Simply try

```
Select LEFT(DATENAME(dw,CAST([DateTime] as Date)),3) as DayName
```

Comment: Second query returns month name right?

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
Select UPPER(LEFT(DATENAME(dw, CAST([DateTime] as Date)), 3)) as DayName
```

Answer (score 1):

This will get the first 3 letters of the day name:

```
Select LEFT(DATENAME(dw,  CAST([DateTime] as Date)),3) as DayName
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use SUBSTRING:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING ( DATENAME(dw,CAST([DateTime] as Date)),3 ,0 , 4 ) as DayName
```

Answer (score 1):

here is example.

```
SELECT 

DATENAME(dw,'09/23/2013') as theDayName ,    

LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,getdate()),3) AS [Short Month Name]
```

http://raresql.com/2013/05/23/sql-server-how-to-get-short-month-name-weekday-name-from-datetime/

the output is

```
theDayName  Short Month Name
Monday       Jun
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @D VARCHAR(10)= '06/09/2014'
SELECT UPPER(SUBSTRING(DATENAME(dw,@D),1,3)) as theDayName 
SELECT UPPER(LEFT(DATENAME(dw,@D),3)) as theDayName
```